# Like button going to wrong URL

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

When I insert my Like button code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpage%2Fto%2Flike&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=35" 
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" 
allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

it doesn't take a person to my URL that I put into the form (www.theREALmeMAGAZINE.com)  I have tried taking out the "www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?" that is listed on the first line of the code and putting my URL in its place, but it didn't work.

I am using Weebly to build my site and it said to use the "iframe" code.  I followed their exact instructions but it is taking me to "Example Domain" when you click the button.

Comment: The Facebook Like Button tool does it for you https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/, just your add URL in 'URL to Like' then get the iframe code.

Answer (score 0):

You're supposed to replace the `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpage%2Fto%2Flike` part (and nothing else) with your URL. Use for example http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/ to encode the URL string to the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

You must replace `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpage%2Fto%2Flike` in the code you give us with `http%3A%2F%2Frealmemagazine.com%2F` and keep the other part of the code intact, as it sets up details like height, send button, layout, etc.

Here's the correct code:

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Frealmemagazine.com%2F&amp;send=false&amp;layout=standard&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=35" 
scrolling="no" frameborder="0" 
style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:35px;" 
allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

The [Facebook Like Button Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) is also available. There, you can get the full code just filling the form. If you don't want to, you can just encode your URL in JavaScript using `escape(URL)` or in PHP with `urlencode()`, or using an [online tool](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/) that can make you this job.